# c# - KeyUp only on one form

Tags: c#, keypress, keyup

I have a poblem.
After press Enter I opening new form (form2), where I can add something to db. 
On Form2 is button Ok. If I this button active by press Enter, I closing form2.

Problem is that by this action I another time calling KeyUp on form1, and Im in loop..

here is example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(KeyEvent);
        }        
private void KeyEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                dataGridViewSkladovePolozky.Focus();
                pridatDoKosiku();
            }
        }
private void buttonPridatDoKosiku_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pridatDoKosiku();
        }
private void pridatDoKosiku()
        {
            PridatDoKosiku pridatDoKosiku = new PridatDoKosiku(); 
            pridatDoKosiku.ShowDialog();
            refreshNakupniKosik(true);
            pridatDoKosiku.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: This is caused by `this.KeyPreview = true;`. If you want to keep this behavior when form2 is opened then in your `KeyEvent` just add `if(form2.Visible) return;`

Comment: There is no particular reason to favor KeyUp.  You probably did this to try to work around the awkward behavior of KeyPreview.  Which is a legacy VB6 property and has VB6 semantics, you won't get the KeyDown event for navigation keys.  Like Enter.  Override ProcessCmdKey() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already marked `KeyPreview` in your form, It will capture all key events. 
You can set a flag & manage like this.

```
bool InFocus = false;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.KeyPreview = true;
                this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(KeyEvent);
            }        
    private void KeyEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
           if(InFocus ) return;
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                {
                    dataGridViewSkladovePolozky.Focus();
                    pridatDoKosiku();
                }
            }
    private void buttonPridatDoKosiku_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pridatDoKosiku();
            }
    private void pridatDoKosiku()
            {
                PridatDoKosiku pridatDoKosiku = new PridatDoKosiku(); 
InFocus = true;
                pridatDoKosiku.ShowDialog();
                refreshNakupniKosik(true);
                pridatDoKosiku.Dispose();
InFocus = false;
            }
```